# Python I/O operation on a closed file, why the error? Code below

Tags: python, io, hashlib

I have the following code, and am getting an error:  I/O operation on a closed file despite having opened the file.

I am creating a .txt file and writing values of a dictionary to the .txt file, then closing the file.

After that I am trying to print the SHA256 digest for the file created.

```
sys.stdout = open('answers.txt', 'w')
for key in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[key])
sys.stdout.close()

f = open('answers.txt', 'r+')
#print(hashlib.sha256(f.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(f.read().encode('utf-8'))
print(m.hexdigest())
f.close()
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filefinder.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "filefinder.py", line 92, in main
    print(m.hexdigest())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you override `sys.stdout` to point to your opened file:

```
sys.stdout = open('answers.txt', 'w')
```

Later, when you try to print to `STDOUT` `sys.stdout` is still pointing to the (now closed) `answers.txt` file:

```
print(m.hexdigest())
```

I don't see any reason to override `sys.stdout` here. Instead, just pass a `file` option to `print()`:

```
answers = open('answers.txt', 'w')
for key in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[key], file=answers)
answers.close()
```

Or, using the `with` syntax that automatically closes the file:

```
with open('answers.txt', 'w') as answers:
    for key in dictionary:
        print(dictionary[key], file=answers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have been overwriting `sys.stdout` with a file handle. As soon as you close it, you can write to it anymore. Since `print()` tries to write to `sys.stdout` it will fail.

You should try opening the file in a different mode (`w+` for example), use a `StringIO` or copy the original `sys.stdout` and restore it later.